# Will my DbContext instance get disposed of in case of exception, when used with Dependency Injection?

Tags: entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-2.1

In typical .NET Core DI scenario, I define the `DbContext` object in repo class level and DI it with constructor. So there’s no need to use using inside any single repo method. In this case, if there’s any exception inside the method, e.g. thrown from `SaveChangesAsync`, will the class level `DbContext` object get disposed of? I guess the answer is probably yes but is there any doc or article talking about this?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Core will take care of this and dispose of the dbcontext regardless.